# Displaying Image in Carousel from MySQLi using PHP Variables

Tags: php, html, mysqli

So I am wanting to create a carousel gallery for my site, so the owners can change the background images when they would like to, and delete images at their will.

Images can already be uploaded, however, displaying them in the carousel is being... difficult.

I am using the MDBootstap Template for the Carousel which looks like this:

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="view" style="background-image: url('http://www.fun4all.org/img/vtc.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
        <!-- Mask & flexbox options-->
        <div class="mask rgba-black-light d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        </div>
        <!-- Mask & flexbox options-->
    </div>
</div>
```

although I have *attempted* to modify the template to be able to show the MySQLi data.

Connection to the Database looks like this: (db.php)

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","highlown_REDACTED","REDACTED");
$db = mysqli_select_db($conn, "highlown_REDACTED");
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM images");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Then how I have attempted to include it within the Gallery

```
<?php
for ($i=1;$i<$rows;$i++) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
?>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="view" style="background-image: url('http://www.URL.org/gallery/img/upload/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['directory']); ?>'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">

                <!-- Mask & flexbox options-->
                <div class="mask rgba-black-light d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">

                </div>
                <!-- Mask & flexbox options-->

            </div>
        </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

I don't really need an explanation on how the stuff works, I just want a correction, please. I will let you know if your answer works or not.

Many Thanks, Ethan B.
*PS, if you need more information, let me know.*

Comment: What exactly is the problem, images not displaying? Did you check if the generated path is correct?

Comment: The path I am intending on it on displaying is correct, however, the image is not displaying, the variable $row['directory'] is not outputting anything into inspect element.